# HTML select element rendered differently on Chrome for macOS and Chrome for Windows

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-platform

Recently part of the app I work on was tested on Windows, and we found that dropdowns/select elements in one particular UI context rendered very differently on Chrome for Windows and Ubuntu than it did on Chrome for macOS.

I have tried inspecting the elements and the styles in Chrome dev tools on the different operating systems, but have been unable to see any difference that could account for the dropdown being as expected in one context, and completely unusable in another.

My question is what could account for this difference, and is there any way in dev tools to see *what* the difference is? I am new to debugging cross-platform styling issues, and am not sure where to start other than the **styles** tab in Chrome dev tools, and I haven't found what I am looking for there.

#### On macOS:

[image]

#### On Windows and Ubuntu:

(in the screenshot it appears as though the months are absent, but they are just white-on-white, so they can't be seen unless they are highlighted):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Selects are mostly styled by the browser / OS. So you can customize it up to a certain point (you can use `-webkit-appearance: none;` to disable some of the default styling, then apply what you need), but to **really** make it look **identical** throughout all platforms, you have to fake it with some regular elements like `div`s and `li`s and JS

Comment: The strange thing is, the app uses numerous select widgets, and only the ones in the calendar are misbehaving.

Comment: so you have other "select" elements that are displayed as that white-on-white version on macOS, such as it is on other OS?

Comment: Now that you mention it, even when it is not white on white (first screenshot), it still looks different than the selects in the rest of our application. I will have to dig deeper into how we are styling those selects in the calendar when I get back to work on Monday.

Comment: @elethan I am also having the same issue. Did you make any progress?